# AC Circuit that lags 135°

Tags: ac, circuit-design, phase-shift

Help! I need to design a circuit with a phase shift of -135° (Vout/Vin). I tried using three -45° (using RC) circuits, then paralleling them (3*45=135). But the angle always lie between 120-128.

My VIN is 10cos(wt) V. And the frequency should be greater than 500Hz. Anyone who can help?

Comment: Did you compensate for ESR and ESL?

Comment: (Oooo, leading 135 degrees. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to show your circuit, and your RC values.  There's no such thing as a circuit with a phase lag of \$45^\circ\$, but there are plenty of ways to make a circuit with a phase of \$45^\circ\$ at a *particular frequency*.

Chances are that your later stages are loading previous stages, altering things slightly.  Try buffering between stages with a voltage follower.  It's also possible that your low freq cutoffs are not all low enough.